# Parsing Date From RSS Feed, Returns NULL

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to parse an RSS Feed.  Things had been working fine, but just recently it started messing up when parsing the pubDate element.  Here is my code for parsing, along with two NSLogs, the first log from what is just simply in the pubDate element of the RSS Feed and the second log when I try to convert that to an NSDate.  This worked fine until late this afternoon for some reason.

```
- (void)parseRss:(GDataXMLElement *)rootElement entries:(NSMutableArray *)entries {

    NSArray *channels = [rootElement elementsForName:@"channel"];
    for (GDataXMLElement *channel in channels) {            

        NSString *blogTitle = [channel valueForChild:@"title"];                    

        NSArray *items = [channel elementsForName:@"item"];
        for (GDataXMLElement *item in items) {
            NSString *articleTitle = [item valueForChild:@"title"];
            NSString *articleUrl = [item valueForChild:@"guid"];            
            NSString *articleDateString = [item valueForChild:@"pubDate"];
            NSLog(@"frompubdate%@", articleDateString);
            NSDate *articleDate = [NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:articleDateString formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC822];
            NSLog(@"fromdate%@", articleDate);
            NSString *articleImage = [item valueForChild:@"description"];
            NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
            [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
            [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
            NSString *dateofarticle = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:articleDate];

            RSSEntry *entry = [[[RSSEntry alloc] initWithBlogTitle:blogTitle articleTitle:articleTitle articleUrl:articleUrl articleDate:articleDate articleImage:bodyoftext] autorelease];      




            [entries addObject:entry];
        }      
    }

}
```

Sun, 28 Oct 201209:30:00 CST

Could not parse RFC822 date: "Sun, 28 Oct 201209:30:00 CST" Possibly invalid format.

Comment: Have you tried to store the articleDate in NSString and then probably try converting the NSString into NSDate with NSDateFormatter class.

Comment: Turns out localendar.com is to blame. No spaces between year and time on their RSS feeds. All my different apps that use them quit working properly at the same time.